How add custom instructions (similar to single and double precision fsqrt) in gem5 targeting RISCV ISA
I want to add custom instructions (similar to single and double precision fsqrt) to carryouts the trigonometric operations in hardware instead of software library so that I can compare the execution time of my targeted workloads for both types of implementations to get an assessment.
Can you please suggest/guide me, for adding a custom instructions like a fsqrt what are all the file in gem5 source/build directory need to modify to correctly execute these operations correctly targeting RISCV ISA?
changed the decoder.isa file and able to add the instructions, but I want not only the adding instruction, but execute the workloads implemented on C/c++.
